# Design Time changes based on MaterialDesignInXAML

Tags: wpf, material-design-in-xaml

I am using MaterialDesignInXAML in WPF using C# (.net Core 3.1).
https://github.com/MaterialDesignInXAML/MaterialDesignInXamlToolkit

**How do I set it to dark mode for the design time editor?**

I set my main window to have:

```
    TextElement.Foreground="{DynamicResource MaterialDesignForeground}"
    Background="{DynamicResource MaterialDesignPaper}"
    FontFamily="{DynamicResource MaterialDesignFont}"
```

App.xaml has:

```
        <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <materialDesign:BundledTheme BaseTheme="Light" PrimaryColor="DeepPurple" SecondaryColor="Lime" />
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MaterialDesignThemes.Wpf;component/Themes/MaterialDesignTheme.Defaults.xaml" />
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
```

There is no code behind.

I know I can modify the Theme at runtime, that is not an issue. But I know there is a way to modify it at design time. *(I want my Visual Studio window to show the dark background etc when editing.)*

When running MaterialDesignToolKit.Full *(from https://github.com/MaterialDesignInXAML/MaterialDesignInXamlToolkit/releases)* The MaterialDesignDemo.

It has dark mode enabled in the editor. I've been looking through it but can't seem to spot why.

I'm sure it's something simple but the app.xaml seems to be the same. I'm missing something obviously.

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you try to set the `BaseTheme` to `Dark` in your `App.xaml`? Or why do you expect the dark theme to be applied?

Comment: Completely missed that part! Thank you that solves my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should set the `BaseTheme` property to `Dark` in your `App.xaml` to apply the dark theme:

```
<materialDesign:BundledTheme BaseTheme="Dark" PrimaryColor="DeepPurple" SecondaryColor="Lime" />
```